# open whatsapp links with web.whatsapp.com

Tags: chromium, mime-type, xdg-open, whatsapp, brave

There is still no way to install a native Linux application for whatsapp, so I always use whatsapp's webapp with my daily browser (chromium based brave-browser).

Everything works [mostly] fine, except when I need to click on a whatsapp link in a web site, that is supposed to open a conversation with a certain new cell phone number. Here's an example on [BOSE's site](https://www.bose.co.uk/en_gb/contact_us.html) when you click in the button "message us".

When I click on a button like that one, I get redirected to [api.whatsapp.com](https://api.whatsapp.com/) and then I get a popup prompt on my browser asking:

```
Open xdg-open?
https://api.whatsapp.com wants to open this application.
```

If I proceed, nothing happens.

I would expect to have a new whatsapp web tab opened to be able to message the new contact.

I have tried to use `xdg-mime` but I can't understand how to use it.

Comment: I found  a snap https://snapcraft.io/whatsdesk and https://github.com/eneshecan/whatsapp-for-linux/releases

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to avoid the xdg popup by blocking JavaScript for api.whatsapp.com through site permissions. Since the webpage has a "continue to chat" link that redirects to web.whatsapp.com, assuming I understood the problem correctly, that link is the solution.

Comment: Wow, that was surprisingly simple. After I blocked JavaScript, the popup was not shown after clicking on "message us". Instead, I was able to click on "continue to chat" in the following page, and web.whatsapp.com was loaded with the appropriate chat opened. Thank you!

Comment: Here are the steps to do this. 
Look for the three dots icon next to your avatar in the upper right corner, click on it and choose the _settings_ option. On the page that opens in the left menu, click _Privacy and security_. 
In the options that appear in the center, click _Site Settings_. At the bottom of the contents section, click _Javascript_. 
At the bottom, in the _Customized behaviors_ section, click the add button for the _Not allowed to use javascript_ option and type in the text box `api.whatsapp.com` and you're done.

Comment: You don't need to block JavaScript. You can right-click on the link and pick open in a new tab or window.

Comment: That's brilliant. It worked, many thanks Martin! I didn't know I can block JavaScript for websites.

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me, just register chrome as whatsapp handler, no need to disable javascript

```
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop 'x-scheme-handler/whatsapp'
```

Comment: That worked for me.

Comment: Does this also rely on the existance of a `.desktop` file (file with a *destkop* extension, as explained at https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/desktop_entries)?

Answer (score 0):

Just hit cancel on the XDG-open prompt.

Then there is javascript on the big green button that triggers the XDG-open stuff again if you click it. You can disable the javascript as other answers suggest, but I prefer to right-click on the button and copy the link or "open in new tab".

You'll get a new web.whatsapp.com tab, you can close the old one that now says: "web.whatsapp is open in other tab".

This is a workaround, as closing the old window might not be desirable (you lose drafts).

Comment: I was trying to avoid the behavior of opening a new whatsapp web session. Specially since you would loose any drafts you were typing in the original session. I think that it is generally preferred to have the handler open a new message in the existing whatsapp web session.